# SQL para contar os caracteres de um campo se é menor que 10

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um grande dificuldade. Tenho a seguinte SQL:

```
$contardescricao  = "0";       
$sqlxmldescricao  = "select id from imoveis where cod = '$cliente' 
                     AND (character_length(descricao)<'10')";
$rsqlxmldescricao = mysql_query($sqlxmldescricao) or die ("Banco XML não abre!");

while($rowxmldescricao = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlxmldescricao))
{
   $contardescricao = $contardescricao + 1;
}
```

Estou tentando fazê-la verificar se o campo `descrição` tem menos que 10 caracteres.

O meu interesse é montar dentro da **estrutura SQL** esta pesquisa para contar o campo **DESCRICAO** de cada registro.

É possível?

Comment: Qual é o problema? Lembre que a verificação dos caracteres é feita em cima de um registros apenas por causa do `cod = '$cliente'`

Comment: @rray entendo, mas este script não exibe de forma exata quantos registros há na tabela que possuem o campo DESCRICAO com menos de 10 caracteres. Queria fazer este recurso dentro da estrutura SQL.

Comment: Quando vc remove `cod = '$cliente'` e deixa apenas: `select id from imoveis where character_length(descricao < '10')` vem certo?

Comment: @rray nada, não funciona!

Comment: Não vem nenhum registro? testou direto no banco? Tem um erro de sintaxe ... que passou, o certo é: `select id from imoveis where character_length(descricao) < 10`

Comment: @rray deu certo, foi falta de eu rodar direto no banco. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Cria uma resposta com os detalhes de adaptou o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o correto seria

```
select id from imoveis where character_length(descricao) < 10
```